# how to print data in given format

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

models.py

```
class ReportPerson(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
def method(request):
    involver_namelist = [] 
    involved = ReportPerson.objects.filter(report=report)
    for involve in involved:
        involver_name =involve.name  
        involver_namelist.append(involver_name)
        print involver_namelist
    return render
```

If i print the data from involver_namelist,it is printing like this as `[u'Admin', u'Admin', u'Admin', u'Admin', u'Admin']` but i want the output like this `Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin` .Is it possible in django.

Comment: where do you want to print ? How would it matter how it prints in the console anyways ?

Comment: @karthikr i need to print  the name in .csv file.It is printing in [u'Admin', u'Admin', u'Admin', u'Admin', u'Admin'] format

Comment: ah.. i see . You might want to update your question to make it clearer. You might more accurate responses. .

Comment: So you need to write the data that you are currently printing to a CSV file correct?

Comment: @RyPeck yes,i tried your solution,it is printed with comma but the name gets repeated more than one times.

Comment: Your original question isn't making much sense at this point. Perhaps you can update it and clarify your intentions further?

Answer (score 0):

When you run `print involver_namelist` it is printing the `list`.

To get the output you desire, replace that line like so -

```
print ", ".join(involver_namelist)
```

This will give you the `Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin, Admin` output you wanted.

[Using the join function for strings.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should define a **repr** method under your model class
in your case, it would be like this:

```
class ReportPerson(models.Model):
    ....
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
```

hope this helps